# installing mysql using pip

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, command-line, pip

I've been trying to install mysql for hours now, I've gone through so many forums and everything can someone help me. Every time I run the command pip install mysql-python I get

---

```
(DjangoProject-env)Adams-MacBook-Air:DjangoProject AdamC$ pip install mysql-python
 Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
   Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
   Running setup.py (path:/Users/AdamC/projects/Environment/DjangoProject-env/build/mysql-        python/setup.py) egg_info for package mysql-python
     sh: mysql_config: command not found
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
       File "/Users/AdamC/projects/Environment/DjangoProject-env/build/mysql-python/setup.py",   line 17, in <module>
         metadata, options = get_config()
       File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
       File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
      EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
       sh: mysql_config: command not found

 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

   File "/Users/AdamC/projects/Environment/DjangoProject-env/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>

     metadata, options = get_config()

    File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config

     libs = mysql_config("libs_r")

    File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config

      raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

   EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

   Cleaning up...
   Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in   /Users/AdamC/projects/Environment/DjangoProject-env/build/mysql-python
  Storing debug log for failure in /Users/AdamC/.pip/pip.log 
  (DjangoProject-env)Adams-MacBook-Air:DjangoPoject AdamC$
```

---

I've tried sourcing a .profile

```
 export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
 export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

And a few other things but I can't remember right now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does not install MySQL itself, it only installs MySQL DB adapter for Python. You first need to install MySQL (can't help you here, as I don't use OSX), or, if you already have it in your system, you need to make it available for MySQL-Python.

Comment: Are you using the built-in system Python?

Comment: Yea I'm pretty sure its version 2.7.6 last time I check, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

try doing

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

later

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error, but I'm not sure if it's from the same situation. I didn't originally have MySQL installed when I was trying to install mysql-python. It therefore couldn't use any MySQL commands like `mysql-config`.

If you don't have Mac Homebrew installed, go here to learn how to install it: http://brew.sh/

Then you can install MySQL with this command:

```
brew install mysql
```

And finally,

```
pip install mysql-python
```

should proceed to completion.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. You can try:

- Step1. Download the Postgres server at www.psequel.com
- Step2. Select
  the Gui Application link and then select the PSequel.
- Step3.Once
  everything has been downloaded, open your Postgres panel and then
  launch the terminal by clicking "open psql." This takes you to the
  terminal. Step4. You can now start using creating databases using
  MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

macos: If you do not use brew you can install mysql from the installer:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/